# Foreign Key Contraint

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

Im adding a row to a database using a form but I keep getting the following error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gigs`.`gig`, CONSTRAINT `gig_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`act`) REFERENCES `act` (`id`))
```

I understand the problem, that the database can't add the form because it can't reference the table ACT_id

But when I add the act ID to the form it doesn't work, this is the php I have been using

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into gig SET venue='$gigvenue', act='$actid', sname='$gigdescription', img='$bandimg', start='$gigstart'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: SQL Injection... Please fix ASAP! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Its on localhost, once I fix the problem I can look into SQL injections

Comment: Sure, just don't write tons of code and then have to go back and change it all. It's best to stick to good standards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too good with SQL, but isn't putting $actid in '' making SQL think it's a string? try dropping the quotes (I assume you're inserting a valid ID).

Comment: The only other thing I can think of: echo $actid;
and see if this ID is actually inside the act table.

Comment: $actid is a form element in html, user inputs it. I have made the value to an ID that I'm 100% is in the parent table